# Female lead learns martial arts from an android

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, action, martial-arts

Looking for an older most likely 1990's science fiction movie that has a female lead who learns martial arts from an android.  I remember the movie was set in post apocalyptic world and had a bit of a *Highlander* feel to it.  Also at one point an android who had no legs attached the legs of a dead android after the main character cut them off at the torso.

Keep in mind I last saw this movie when I was like 10 years old or so... yeah.. not the best description I know.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the movie you are thinking of is [Knights](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107333/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), circa 1993. From the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_%28film%29) page:

> The cyborg Gabriel (Kris Kristofferson) was created to destroy all other cyborgs. He later rescues Nea (Kathy Long) by killing Simon (Scott Paulin), one of the other cyborgs. Gabriel trains Nea to become a cyborg killer and help him. They continue to kill cyborgs until **Gabriel is torn in half by one of his targets** and taken to the cyborg camp. Nea follows Jacob and challenges the cyborg leader Job (Lance Henriksen) to a fight. She ends up killing most of the cyborgs in the camp.
>
> **She finds Gabriel and straps him to her back.** Together, they battle the cyborgs until Gabriel has her put him down so he can attach a dead cyborg's legs to himself. They then pursue a fleeing Job, but before they can catch him the Master Builder captures Nea's brother, taking him to Cyborg City. Meanwhile, Gabriel is battling Job and hits him in the face, causing it to explode. Job tells Gabriel that the cyborg population can't be stopped. Job dies moments later. Gabriel and Nea ride off into the sunset, in search of her brother and Cyborg CityCleaned.

Side note: At first I thought your movie was [Circuitry Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099271/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl), since it also has a woman and robot traveling around in a post apocalyptic world.

Answer (score 0):

Could it [be Metallic Attraction: Kungfu Cyborg](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1494775/)? It's a Chinese movie from 2009 starring Wu Jing as one of the leads. I was thinking of this because you mentioned martial arts (and androids of course)..

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP dates the movie to the 1990s.

Comment: Well, "most likely 1990's", so I thought I'd give it a shot anyway ;)